# compare 2 numbers and print message if is greater than 10

Tags: php

I want get 2 timestamps  from 2 different links and compare if the difference is greater than 10 minutes. If it is, I want to print a message.

The timestamp is in this format:

> Fri, 02 Dec 2016 18:47:40 GMT

This is my code:

```
$1=get_headers("http://example.com", 1);
$2=get_headers("http://example1.com", 1);
$a1=$1["Last-Modified"];
$a2=$2["Last-Modified"];

$mins = ($a1- $a2) / 60;
echo $mins;
```

and then I think next is something like:

```
$mins > 10      
echo "its bigger then 10";
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `strtotime` function to convert from string format to a number format (the result is the number of seconds passed from 1/1/1970). Once you have the values as numbers you can do you math:

```
$headers_1=get_headers("http://example.com", 1);
$headers_2=get_headers("http://example1.com", 1);

$a1 = strtotime($headers_1["Last-Modified"]);
$a2 = strtotime($headers_2["Last-Modified"]);

$mins = ($a1-$a2) / 60;
if ($mins > 10) {
    echo "its bigger then 10";
}
```

Comment: example now this Fri, 02 Dec 2016 20:16:33 GMT
is converted to 1480709793  : can u exmplain what is this number

Comment: what? i don't understand what the comment is regarding

Comment: so echo $mins; is telling how much minute is difference between 2 times?

Comment: @arpak, keep in mind that you might wanna check `abs($mins) > 10`